# Boolean searching with tags and answered status?

Tags: support

Is there a way to do a boolean search with tags and answered or unanswered status? For example, I found myself wanting to search for something like this: ([networking] and not [wireless])and(unanswered)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude a tag you just enter `-[wireless]`

So for your search you'd want to search for one of:

- `[networking] -[wireless] answers:0`
- `[networking] -[wireless] hasaccepted:0`

Answer (score -1):

To limit search results to questions with no answers, put `answers:0` in the query. For questions with accepted answers, you need `hasaccepted:1` (opposite: `hasaccepted:0`)

I'm afraid that there is no such thing as "exclude tag from search query".

See also https://askubuntu.com/search